# Not numbering Remarks

Tags: numbering, theorems

If I have the following

```
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
```

I will obtain Remark 1, Remark 2 and so on. May I know how to remove the numbering in Remark? Like I just want the word "Remark" and not the number 1, 2, 3 and so on.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By reading the documentation of `amsthm` you will find that this definition:

```
\newtheorem*{}{}
```

allows you to not have numbers.

Look at this MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{The social interaction}
\begin{remark}[Homophily]
Homophily is the principle that a contact between similar people occurs at a
higher rate than among dissimilar people.
\end{remark}

\begin{remark}[Social distance]
Social distance describes the distance between different groups of society and is opposed to locational distance
\end{remark}

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: It may be worth noting that the method of using a "starred" theorem-like environment also works with the `ntheorem` package. The only difference is that, with the `ntheorem` package in use instead of the `amsthm` package, the optional title of the remark will be typeset in bold rather than in "plain" upright font.

Comment: @Mico That all can be set up using `amsthm` as well ;) But you are right that `ntheorem` provides more configutation possibilities.

Comment: @tohecz -- Thanks for this. I certainly didn't mean to imply that one couldn't configure the `amsthm` package to typeset the optional argument of theorem-like environments in bold font. My main point was to mention that there's another excellent package out there, besides `amsthm`, that the OP could make use of.

Comment: the text of remarks is most often set in upright type.  with `amsthm`, precede your `\newtheorem*` statement by `\theoremstyle{remark}`.

Comment: @Mico no worries :)